# php code for multiple search box after connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a search form in PHP. I have a first name, last name, dob, city and many fields in it. When I enter only first name and search, it should print the info of the user I entered. Similarly, when I enter the city name and search, it should output all users in the city.

Here is my PHP code:

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $num=$_POST['Fielformd1'];
               $statement = $myconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE vorname LIKE '$num' ");
               $statement->execute();
               $key = $statement->fetchall();
               foreach($key as $value){
                   echo '
'.$value['vorname'].
                   ' - '.$value['nachname'].
                   ' - '.$value['strasse'].
                   ' - '.$value['plz'].
                   ' - '.$value['ort'].
                   ' - '.$value['email'].
                   ' - '.$value['telefon'].
                   ' - '.$value['mobil'].'
'; 
               } 
          }
          else{
               echo"enter correct name again";
          }
          }

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to this community! We would be happy to help you fix your existing code, but we are not here to write  code for you.

Comment: @ArunkumarK where's the code?

Comment: I added above. .

Comment: Can you share your html form or ajax request with us too ?

Comment: <form  method="post" action="example.php"  id="searchform">
  <input type="text" name="vorname"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: Here is your problem: $name=$_POST['submit']; it needs to be $name=$_POST['vorname']; or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can try change it to something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="example.php" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="keyword">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['keyword'];
    $statement = $myconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE (ort LIKE '%$name%') OR (plz LIKE '%$name%') OR (vorname LIKE '%$name%')");
    $statement->execute();
    $key = $statement->fetchall();
    foreach($key as $value){
        echo '<br/>'.$value['vorname'].
            ' - '.$value['nachname'].
            ' - '.$value['strasse'].
            ' - '.$value['plz'].
            ' - '.$value['ort'].
            ' - '.$value['email'].
            ' - '.$value['telefon'].
            ' - '.$value['mobil'].'<br/><br/>';
    }
}
else{
    echo"enter correct name again";
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Please mark this answer as correct so it can help other people too.